# CSV to Json on a windows server

Tags: asp.net, json, csv

I'm a front end web developer and I'm trying to convert a CSV file to Json on the server. The server is a windows server with asp.net on it. I thought this would be a simple thing to do but after googling around for a few hours I see it's a bit harder then I original thought. I see there are a bunch of converters online that you can paste your code into and do a one time conversion but these will not work for me because my CSV file will be updated by another program. Does anyone know how to do this conversion using .net or know of a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Use it to read your CSV.

The you should be able to use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to output Json.